# How to draw a contour around a shape in a picture?

Tags: android, matrix, canvas, bitmap, scale

As you can see in the picture, I want to expand the of the parts I show with arrows and draw a contour, is there a way to do this?

What I really want to do is expand the matrix on the back and draw the normal picture on it.

[image: Click to see the picture]
[image: Click to see the picture]

Comment: if you have a path of image you can do it.

Comment: @Style-7 No, there is no picture path, I want to draw a contour around the picture selected from the gallery

Comment: You can draw a color mask (orange in your picture) to a bitmap. Calculate a shift vector by angle from 0 to 360 (step may be from 1 to 90 according to quality) and draw. So it will be as blur shadow, so just draw source bitmap on the top.

Comment: @Style-7 I've used a loop like this before, but it reacts very slowly.

Comment: private Bitmap StrokeBitmap(){
 int strokeWidth = 10;
 Bitmap stroke = Bitmap.createBitmap(getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels, getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(stroke);
    for (int i = 0; i < 360; i++){
        canvas.drawBitmap(originalBitmap, (int)(strokeWidth+Math.sin(i) * strokeWidth), (int)(strokeWidth + Math.cos(i) * strokeWidth), null);
    }
    canvas.drawColor(strokecolor, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
    canvas.drawBitmap(originalBitmap, strokeWidth,strokeWidth, null);
    return stroke;
}

Comment: @Style-7 I used the code with the above loop. But he reacted late, is there any way you can suggest?

Comment: change step in the loop i += 15

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So use this custom view as example

[image]

```
public class ViewHighLight extends View{
    final Bitmap bms; //source
    final Bitmap bmm; //mask
    final Paint paint;
    final int width = 4;
    final int color_highlight = 0xff00ff00;
    final int step = 15; // 1...45

    public ViewHighLight( Context context ){
        super( context );
        bms = BitmapFactory.decodeResource( getResources(), R.drawable.b );
        bmm = Bitmap.createBitmap( bms.getWidth(), bms.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ALPHA_8 );
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas( bmm );
        canvas.drawBitmap( bms,0,0, null );
        paint = new Paint( Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG );
        paint.setColor( color_highlight );
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw( Canvas canvas ){
        super.onDraw( canvas );

        // draw blur shadow
        for( int i = 0; i < 360; i+=step ){
            float x = width * (float)Math.cos( Math.toRadians( i ) );
            float y = width * (float)Math.sin( Math.toRadians( i ) );
            canvas.drawBitmap( bmm, x,y, paint );
        }
        //draw source bitmap on the top
        canvas.drawBitmap( bms, 0,0, null );

        //draw bitmap on the right for compare
        canvas.drawBitmap( bms, bms.getWidth(),0, null );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very very very much, it was a really big problem for me :)

Comment: How to caculate postion, if canvas.drawBitmap( bms, x,y, null ), with x and y custom